# Can I 'reserve' memory somehow, so as to ensure malloc doesn't fail for this reason

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Is it possible to 'reserve' memory before a `malloc()` call? In other words, can I do something (perhaps OS-specific) which ensures there is a certain amount of free memory available, so that you know that your next `malloc()` (or `realloc()` etc.) call won't return NULL due to lack of memory?

The 'reservation' or 'pre-allocation' can fail just like a malloc, but if it succeeds, I want to be sure my next malloc() succeeds.

Notes:

- Yes, I know, I want to allocate memory before allocating memory. That's exactly right. The thing is the later allocations are not really under my control and I want to be able to assume they succeed.
- Bonus points for an answer regarding multi-threaded code as well.
- My motivation: I was considering adopting the use of [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) for my C development, but apparently it `abort()`s when it fails to allocate memory, and that's not acceptable to me.
- Perhaps a solution which dynamically replaces the malloc symbol with something else? Or the symbol for the function wrapping the sbrk system call?

Comment: `malloc()` shouldn't "fail"; it should simply return `NULL`. And as for reserving memory, how could you do this if there isn't any memory available? Best bet is to simply check the return value from `malloc()`.

Comment: Threading won't matter, as all threads in a process share the same pool of memory from which they allocate.

Comment: Reserving memory is exactly what `malloc` does, you want to reserve before reserving?

Comment: Also remember that memory allocation can fail not because of there's not enough memory, but because of fragmentation (no memory chunk large enough).

Comment: Design your application/system in a way, it would/could survive in case `malloc()` & Friends returned `NULL`.

Comment: @Kninnug: Exactly, that's what I want to do. And the reason is in the motivation - there are malloc's which I can't control.

Comment: For situations like this you would generally provide your own implementation of `malloc()`; either replacing the system one, or by passing the alternative implementation into the library somehow.  However, if your OS overcommits (most do) then a successful result from `malloc()` does still not guarantee that the memory is available.  The OS may kill your task when it realises it can't live up to the promises it made.

Comment: @alk: frequently this problem arises and it's not the application's fault. For example, GMP cannot recover from memory allocation failure, so if you want to write an application that can survive *and* you want to use this (otherwise) very useful library, then you must resort to trickery. An alternative is to use two processes -- one that invokes the fragile library (whether it's GMP or something else) and another that is robust to out-of-memory. Finally it's worth remembering that on e.g. linux, your process might be taken down by an OOM killer whether it aborts or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With glibc you can hook the allocation functions:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

Now that you control memory allocation in your program, you can do what you like, including writing a function to reserve a (possibly thread-local, since you asked about multi-threading) chunk of memory from the system that future calls to your `malloc` and `realloc` hooks will use to return memory.

Obviously, you need to somehow know in advance an upper bound how much memory will be required by the series of `malloc` calls that you need to not fail.

Comment: "Never underestimate the complexity of glib", or something. :)

Answer (score 3):

Back in the old Mac Toolbox days it was extremely common to use a chunk of memory called a "rainy-day fund." You'd allocate enough memory such that if you freed it, there'd be enough free memory to throw up a dialog box explaining that the app had run out of memory, save your work, and exit. Then you'd keep that pointer around until `malloc()` returned null, and at least you'd be guaranteed to be able to deal with it gracefully.

That was on a 100% real-memory system, though, and things these days are very different. Still, if we're talking about those small and simple real-memory systems that still exist, then a similar strategy still makes sense.

Comment: If I put a critical section around a rainy-day-fund de-allocation and a glib call, then that might work - but I don't think doing that each and every call is worthwhile. Or are you suggesting something else?

Comment: For your specific case, it seems like [Steve Jessop's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17489963/659804) is far and away the best: glib provides a hook for dealing with out-of-memory conditions before they happen. I suspect your hook function would keep a rainy-day fund that could be freed if `malloc()` had no more memory to give.

Answer (score 2):

I realize the following does not directly answer your question with respect to malloc().  It is instead an attempt to offer up another avenue that might be applicable to your situation.

For a few years I was dealing with certified embedded systems.  Two of the constraints were that 1) we were forbidden to free memory and 2) we were forbidden from allocating memory beyond a certain point during the initialization process.  This was because fragmentation that could result from dynamic memory allocations and deallocations made it too costly to certify (and guarantee that allocations would succeed).

Our solution was to allocate pools of memory during the early initialization process.  The blocks of memory handled by a given pool would all be the same size, thereby avoiding the fragmentation issue.  Different pools would handle differently sized memory blocks for a different purpose.  This meant that we had to allocate enough memory up front for our worst case memory consumption scenario as well as manage those pools ourselves.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, not really, because you're describing a scenario in which you controlled all of the code, while I'm working with code a lot of which is out of my control and does not conform to my memory use policies.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there's no magic way for your program to ensure your system has an arbitrary amount of memory, but you can get the memory as soon as your process starts, so that it won't fail unexpectedly part way through the work/day when it'll be a right pain.

On some OSes, simply doing a big malloc then freeing the memory immediately will still have called `sbrk` or similar OS function to grow your process memory, but even that's not a great solution because getting virtual address space is still a ways short of getting physical memory to back it when needed, so you'd want to write through that memory with some noise values, then even if it's swapped out to disk while unused you can expect that the virtual memory of the system is committed to your memory needs and will instead deny other programs (or smaller new/malloc requests you make later ;-P) memory should the system be running short.

Another approach is to seek an OS specific function to insist on locking memory pages in physical memory, such as `mlock(2)` on Linux.

(These kind of "I'm the most important thing on the server" assumptions tend to make for a fragile system once a few running programs have all taken that attitude....)

Comment: I don't want to be the most important thing on the server. I'm willing to 'fail', but I want it to be in the reservation, or pre-allocation phase, not during the malloc. Editing to that effect.